# How do I get the browser to auto refresh when editing .razor files?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

How do I get the browser to auto refresh when I make a change to the markup within a blazor-webassembly file (.razor files)? The Visual Studio 2022 documentation indicates that it's unsupported, however I have seen this demonstrated in YouTube videos. Was this feature removed once out of preview?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate hot reload on save with Blazor WASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340426/how-to-activate-hot-reload-on-save-with-blazor-wasm)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, tried all those suggestions with no luck. That thread was more about hot reload. My inquiry is in regards to auto refresh.

Comment: Well, auto refresh would require hot reload (due to how Blazor works), and if you don't have hot reload, you can't have auto refresh. Also, the accepted answer on that page says, "It reloads the web page on the browser" (which is the definition of "refresh"). Are you saying that it doesn't reload the web page on the browser?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey. I went ahead and edited the markup, hit the hot reload button and nothing happened in the browser. I also tried it in release mode. I also tried by starting the project with dotnet watch command as noted in the other thread. It does seem to detect a change but the page does not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are using Response Compression Middleware (`UseResponseCompression()`) in the `Program.cs` file.

It seems that this middleware [is no longer needed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/comment-page-3/#:%7E:text=app.UseResponseCompression()) for Blazor Webassembly, and that for some people [removing the installation of the middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41732#:%7E:text=Hot%20reload%20works%20when%20I%20remove) `UseResponseCompression()` fixes the problem of getting an error when attempting to hot reload. Some Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server#:%7E:text=Add-,Response%20Compression%20Middleware,-services%20to%20Program) says to use the compression middleware, but this breaks the hot reload functionality, in my exprience. Once this call is removed, hot reload works for running with the Debugger attached and not attached.

[I gave the same answer to another question, but have repeated it here because I wasn't sure it was the same question.]